# compareTo in WritableComparable is intended for?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to emit 2 matrices as my key and value. One matrix as key and the other as value.
I wrote my class which implements WritableComparable.

But I am confused what to write with in:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(MW o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

What is this CompareTo() intended for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To cite the Java documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class
>   that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's
>   natural ordering, and the class's compareTo method is referred to as
>   its natural comparison method.

Usually you return 0 if both objects are the same, and with a number higher or lower you determine the order between your objects.

Comment: In my case i am emiting 2 matrices and both of these matrices are different. so how comparison happens?

Comment: Just compare element-wise like you normally do with a matrix.

Comment: but i think those matrix can be equal or different after computation ;).Tat makes me lot of confusions, Tat doesn't matter oh wat? need to jst compare them element wise?

Comment: whether CompareTo() is intended for comparing key and value OR comparing value to value,key to key?

Comment: it doesn't matter, it compares two objects of the same class.

Comment: I wrote like this boolean ret = Arrays.equals(values, o.values);Is tat correct?and wt to return?